# Can we host wsdl files on a different server than the server on which the actual soap service is running

Tags: soap, wsdl

I don't want my clients to access wsdls from the server on which soap application is running. Hence I want my wsdls to be accessible to clients from another server which just serves the purpose of making wsdl files accessible which client can directly consume to access the actual soap service.

How should I go about it.

Answer (score 0):

> I think you can achieve this by replacing the web service url in your
>   WSDL file. for e.g. your web service implementation is running over
>   192.168.0.20 and your wsdl file is deployed on 192.168.0.21, now change web service url in your WSDL file.
>   e.g.
>   you can find this code snippet at bottom of your wsdl file.

```
<wsdl:service name="TestWebService">
        <wsdl:port binding="impl:TestWebServiceBinding" name="TestWebService">
           <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/Project/services/TestWebService"/>
        </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>

to    

<wsdl:service name="TestWebService">
     <wsdl:port binding="impl:TestWebServiceBinding" name="TestWebService">
         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://192.168.0.21:8080/Project/services/TestWebService"/>
     </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

hope it will work and one more thing you have to configure ssl on your both server to access the cross domain.

Thanks